# comparar dos horas en java

Tags: java, date

estoy tratando de comparar dos horas para poder cargar precios dependiendo de la hora(para un parqueo).

```
public static String horaNoche = "19:00:00";  
public static String horaDia = "07:00:00";  //Estos dos strings los obtengo
                                            //de una clase Hora
                                      //y la llamo en Hora h=new Hora();


public void cargarprecios(){
    String hora=h.obtenerHora();
    try{
Date date1 = dateFormat.parse(hora);
    Date cambioHora=dateFormat.parse(h.horaNoche);
    Date cambioHora2=dateFormat.parse(h.horaDia);
    if(date1.compareTo(cambioHora) < 0 && date1.compareTo(cambioHora2)>0){
        int i=date1.compareTo(cambioHora);
        System.out.println(i);
        m.cargarpreciosDIA();
    }
    else 
        if(date1.compareTo(cambioHora) >= 0 && date1.compareTo(cambioHora2)<0){
            int j=date1.compareTo(cambioHora);
            System.out.println(j);
            m.cargarpreciosNOCHE();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
    }

}
```

un ejemplo de el problema al que me enfrento, es que un carro entra a las 23:00:00  y sale a las 01:00:00 , me tire los precios de noche, porque los precios de dia son hasta las 07:00:00.

Pero tanto sea dia o de noche, no hace las comparaciones y no me carga los precios

Answer (score 1):

Si usas una version de java inferior a Java 8 puedes usar joda.datetime

http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html

Este api tiene un DateTimeComparator para comparar fechas

```
DateTimeComparator.getInstance().compare(date1, date2);
```

http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/

Si usas java 8 ya este tiene un api, y puedes comparar usando isAfter is equal o isBefore

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#isAfter-java.time.chrono.ChronoLocalDate-